# How to check current_user is present in particular recordset?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Three tables User,Event and EventInvitee.
A user creates an event and invites other users in that event.
Now using below code I get all the users invited in a particular event.

```
@event=Event.find(4)
 @event.event_invitees
```

but now I want to check that current_user is present in @event.event_invitees?

How can I do that?

fields of EventInvitee table are id,user_id,event_id and relationship is defined properly among those three table.

please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that `current_user` is exists in selected `EventInvite`'s use [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) method:

```
@event.event_invitees.exists?(user_id: current_user.id)
```